# Domain Not loading in 3g or LTE but works perfectly in Wifi

Tags: apache, dns, server, 3g, lte

I have recently finished my website and uploaded code to server. It is working perfectly when connected to Wi-fi or broadband connection.

But When i am connecting the site using 3G or LTE it's showing some default page. Exact domain is not loading.

Still not able to understand why it's happening.

My Domain name: http://www.jockdrive.com

Please help me with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There might be cached data stored on the server of the Interner Service provider. Normally, ISPs clear cached data every 24-48 hours (in rare cases 72). This is called propagation.

If you want to see an up-to-date and uncached version of your website, check it via proxy server. Here is the link: https://kproxy.com/

Comment: Thanks for the your suggestion but it's not a permanent solution i site is up from last 1 month and still unable to open it in 3G or LTE network.

Answer (score 0):

```
;QUESTION
www.jockdrive.com. IN AAAA
;ANSWER
www.jockdrive.com. 3600 IN AAAA 2607:f1c0:1000:80f9:71ce:7028:7b2e:b009
```

Your domain name is probably configured with wrong IPv6 address, and I guess  cellular operators are using that as default when available. You can try deleting that record (or check with your hosting provider if they can provide the correct one) and see if it helps.