# Website not loading on AT&T LTE; all other carriers and wifi work fine

Tags: android, iphone, dns, shopify, lte

I built a website in Shopify, see it here: [practicalamerican.com](http://practicalamerican.com)

The site loads fine on desktop, mobile, wifi, every carrier - except AT&T. In the later case, the browser gives an error that there is no internet connection. Presumably, it never receives a response from the server, so it makes that determination.

Loading any other site works fine. I've confirmed this on multiple devices and multiple browsers, Android and iPhone. Weirdly, if I toggle Wifi on my iPhone and load the page, then toggle Wifi off and try to reload the page, it loads fine. Perhaps some sort of browser caching? Not sure how it would determine it has an internet connection as per the previous point.

I've tried: adding `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-transform">`

I've tried deleting every script tag to which Shopify gives access.

I've tried accessing practical-american.myshopify.com (bypassing the DNS record).

All with no success. Any other ideas?

UPDATE: I tried using a proxy, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40547937/947437) and I can view the page fine. Perhaps this is a DNS record caching issue with AT&T? Hopefully, it will clear soon. It's Black Friday right now, we just emailed 10,000 customers!

Comment: You'll probably get a better response from Shopify support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue cleared about 72 hours after it started. That seems consistent with DNS caching, as suggested by [Ira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40547937/947437). The other proof is that when the page was loaded on Wifi, I could then reload it on LTE, but I could not load it on LTE in an empty browser tab.